# BER for DPSK with decision regions

Tags: digital-communications

In this response https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/79258/235, the calculation for the BER of an 8-PSK is performed. Can we use the same method for a differential modulation (DPSK) for example DQPSK? I tried but can't see how to deal with the differential modulation part.

Comment: hi! That depends on how your receiver works; since a DPSK receiver has memory, it's a bit more complicated to write down the maximum likelihood detector for AWGN (it effectively needs to be a MLSE). However, DPSK is almost exclusively used when, due to complexity, that ML detector isn't used, or, when due to fast fading, the channel changes quickly, but then the channel is not AWGN. Can you write down in your question what kind of channel you're assuming and what kind of DPSK receiver you are considering?

Comment: I guess you're implying that, as well, but is it OK to assume your DPSK uses Gray mapping for the bits-to-differential phase mapping?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DPSK versus PSK error probability](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/62528/235) whose answer describes how an optimal DPSK receiver actually works.  For DQPSK, see my answer to [How to soft decode DQPSK?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/8051/235)